# How to make the div stick to top, on the same time center of page?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with fixed height and width, that I centered using margin left and right `auto`. But I want this bar visible throughout my page, so that I glued it using `position:absolute`. But then the bar comes to left and is not centered anymore. How can I pin the bar to center top position?

```
<div class="bar">bar</div>

.bar{
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/hkZju/) is the fiddle.

Comment: You can use `position: fixed;` and use `top` and `right` values to determine its exact position on the screen. Caveat: it will not move if the user scrolls/etc.

Comment: @TylerH can u show me a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a 100% width container div, fixing that to the top, and then putting your bar centered inside it.
CSS:

```
.bar{
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:orange;
}
.container
{
width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkZju/6/)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/hkZju/12/

```
.bar{
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
   margin-left:-200px;
    background-color:orange;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bar{
width: 400px;
height: 40px;
left : 50%;
margin-left:-200px;
top : 0%;
position : absolute;
background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: it is guaranted... try it out @javad. see carefully i am using "margin-left"

Comment: @Javad on margin left 50%, the div will be having 50% on left, that is, the div will start from the middle of the page, to right. Giving it a -ve margin of 50% of it's width (here 200px) will definitely pull the mid point of div to the center of the page.

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ yes you are right I'm sorry; I did not see the width is 400px; but what if the width was in percent?

Comment: how can width be in percent? and if it can be then you will have to apply some other method

Answer (score 0):

So the bar will remain in top, even if you scroll the page, you have to use `position:fixed`. Then, to center it, set the left to 50%, and the `margin-left` to minus the half of the width.

```
.bar{
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hkZju/9/

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to put the `.bar` inside a div which has `position: absolute` and `width: 100%`

Check this fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hkZju/8/)

```
.bar{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}

.bar div {
   width: 400px;
   height: 40px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   background-color:orange;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding either:

`position: fixed top right;`

Like TylerH said, or

`position:absolute top right;`

Would be your best options. More flexible.

Fixed to always show, Absolute to "pin" to page.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using jquery by dynamically changing the left value of the div, below is the code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bar').css('left',($(document).width() - $('.bar').width())/2);
});
```

Or if you want to do it with css - add the below css properties

```
.bar{
 left : 50%;
 margin-left:-200px;//should be half in the width of the div
}
```